# I need to unsee characters in git status

Tags: git, gitignore, status

I'm currently doing an exercise with Git and I cannot take those '??' in the beginning away and i need to.

Can someone explain to me how to!?

Much appreciate it!

I'm a beginner by the way, obviously!

It is an exercise where i need to write a short shell script where it shows the list of ignored archives present in my local repository.

`ex06 % git status -s --ignored=traditional | grep '??*'`

`?? .DS_Store`
`?? mywork.c~`

Answer (score 1):

Side note: *unsee* is the wrong verb; for more about this see [know your meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/what-has-been-seen-cannot-be-unseen), and for interesting further side exploration, see [this article in *The Atlantic*](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2014/05/10-things-you-cant-unsee-and-what-that-says-about-your-brain/361335/).

What to understand here, with respect to `git status -s`, is that Git's output is a *series of plain-text lines*, and on a reasonably capable system—including your Mac<sup>1</sup>—you have text-line-handling tools.  **These tools are not part of Git itself.**  You're doing general programming here.  One of the tools is `sed`, the *stream editor*, and using `sed` you can make the same change to every output line, such as removing three characters.

You are already doing this same sort of thing with `grep`: the `grep` command is short for `g/re/p`, which is an old<sup>2</sup> editor command meaning *find every line containing the regular expression `re`, and print it*.  If you're going to edit the lines further with `sed`, there's no need to use `grep` first as `sed` can subsume the match-and-print task: `sed -n -e '/??*/s/...//p'` will do what you're doing with `grep` *and* subsequently remove three initial characters.<sup>3</sup>

But, since this is more of a general Unix programming question, this (tags involving Git) is the wrong place to ask it.

---

<sup>1</sup>We can guess that you are on a Mac based on the existence of the file `.DS_Store`, which is created by the MacOS Finder.

<sup>2</sup>Positively ancient: `ed`, the text editor that does this, is [from the 1960s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)).  Technically the first *Unix* `ed` was in the 1970s but it was based on a 1960s editor.

<sup>3</sup>Note that `??*` matches one question mark anywhere in the string; you probably really wanted `^??`.  The asterisk `*` is a suffix operator meaning *zero or more occurrences* and hence `??*` is functionally identical to just `?`.  The usefulness of the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) here comes in only with additional characters *after* the `*`, or when using the matched text directly in some way.

Note further that [*regular expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matching is different from [*glob*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) matching.  The two are related, but REs are much more powerful: a glob pattern can be turned into a regular expression, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback and info! Really helped!

Comment: (See also jthill's answer, for an in-Git way to do this without external tools.)

Answer (score 1):

> It is an exercise where i need to write a short shell script where it shows the list of ignored archives present in my local repository

`git status` is the wrong tool for this. You want a list of files in the work tree, the right tool is almost always `git ls-files`. In your case, it's `git ls-files -oci --exclude-standard` and if there's a pattern to your archive names like `'*.zip'` give that and any others too (with the surrounding quotes so the shell doesn't expand it, you want git doing that for this).